# Can't see Funnels Option in Firebase Analytics Dashboard

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I have used Firebase Analytics in my Android Application. I have logged multiple events and I can see my events in Firebase Console. But till the first week of December 2021, I can see the Funnels option available in the Analytics Dashboard of Firebase Console, and now it is not visible. Funnels is very important for me to understand the user journey in the application. Can anyone help me to enable Funnels in Firebase Analytics or else is there any alternative for the Funnels in Firebase Analytics Console.

Previous Options -->

[image: Previous Options]

Current Options -->

[image: Current Options]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few months ago the Analytics pages in the Firebase console were updated to better align with their counterparts in the Google Analytics 4 dashboard. From the documentation describing the [changes](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/11091821):

| Google Analytics for Firebase feature | Change to align with Google Analytics 4 |
| --- | --- |
| ... | ... |
| Funnels | The Funnels feature was removed from Analytics for Firebase as of December 2021. Going forward, use the funnel [exploration technique](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9327974) in Google Analytics 4 Explorations. |
| ... | ... |

Check out the links above and this [blog post announcing the change](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/11/updated-google-analytics-dashboard.html) for full details.